# Oracle how to update using ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, sorting, oracle11g, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a requirement to update a dataset after sorting it, in pl/sql. Here's is the dynamic SQL.

```
    v_dyn_sql:= 'UPDATE '||v_in_schema||'.'||v_in_skinny_table||'
                    SET BATCH=CEIL(ROWNUM/'||v_in_source_batch_size||') 
                    WHERE
                        RECORD_STATUS IN '||v_in_mode||'
                    AND 
                        LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C in (SELECT LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
                                          FROM '||v_in_schema||'.'||v_in_wide_table||'
                                          ORDER BY '||v_in_sort_criteria)
```

***Id is not unique so the `MERGE` statement does not work for me.

So this should sort the dataset, and then update the first `v_in_source_batch_size` rows with 1, second `v_in_source_batch_size` rows with 2, and so forth.

How can I achieve this result? Is using a cursor the only way? If so, how can I make the cursor dynamic?

Comment: you can loop over this as a cursor in a PLSQL and issue updates one at a time.

Comment: How can I create a cursor dynamically for this case?

Answer (score 2):

```
begin
  for i in (select * from <table>
            order by col1) loop
    update <table> set <col>=<col_value> where <col>=i.<col_pk>;
  end loop;
end;
```

Try something like this - you can use where current of to access the current row in the cursor and dispense with the where clause part of the update if you like

Comment: Should indicate that the `select * from <table>` clause would need the `ORDER BY` applied, in order to satisfy the requirements.